# Consider the increasing, concave function $x^{0.5}$ on $[0, 1]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Consider the increasing, concave function: 
$$ g(x) = \sqrt x, x ∈ [0, 1]. $$

Can you state a continuous function:
$$ f(x), x ∈ [0, 1] $$

such that $f(0) = 0, f(x)$ is twice continuously differentiable on $(0, 1]$ and:

$$ 0 < f'< g', f'' > |g''|  $$

for all $x ∈ (0,1]$ ?

So basically I want an increasing function $f(x)$ which has a lower slope than $g(x)$ everywhere but is more convex than $g(x)$ is concave everywhere.

Comment: How coud $g$ be $C^2$ on $[0,1]$ when its second derivative has to blow up at $0?$

Comment: Question edited. See if it is possible to find a suitable function now. I do not think it is possible even now. I suppose the problem is that g(x) becomes "almost infinitely" concave near x = 0 and so as f(x) would need to become "almost infinitely" convex near x = 0, its first derivative would necessarily become larger than the first derivative of g(x) at x close to 0. Does this sound about right?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose such an $f$ exists. Then for $0<x<1$ the condition on $f''$ implies

$$f'(1) - f'(x) = \int_x^1 f''(t)\, dt \ge \int_x^1 \frac{1}{4t^{3/2}}\, dt.$$

This implies $f'(x) \to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+.$ That violates the $f'>0$ condition, giving a contradiction.